# DB alert on values change

Tags: postgresql, psql

How to make notification when some conditions written by user are true.

I have one table **DATA** which has 3 rows.

```
name  value
----  -----
a1    10
a2    20
a3    30
```

This table changes some values every 1-10 minutes.

Example: a1=12 , a2=21

ALERT:
if `a1>11` and `a2>20` send me some message.

Question: How to check when a value in DATA fulfils the conditions in alert, and then my php/python environment takes any action on this alarm?

My idea:

- After update on DATA table run trigger that will check if ALERT exist and set active on it (how to check when DATA id a1=12 and then check if there is some alert like a1>11)
- Run every 1 minute process that checks if ALERT is active and execute it.

I don't now where to start...

I will use: PostgreSQL, php, cron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple choices here.

- writing a crontab that will check every minutes your data (that's what you propose).
- using NOTIFY/LISTEN with trigger like this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_check_data_value()
  RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
  SELECT pg_notify('data', NEW.value);
END;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER check_data_values_trigger
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE f_check_data_value();
```

You'll then have to write a listener (in PHP if it's what you are using). I haven't used php inn a while but the php.net documentation is a good place to start I think : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.pg-get-notify.php

Comment: thx for. i have make this. 1. add triger after update, 2. add nodejs listener who make POST with  new value , 3. backend queue all post.